# How can i get the same value for round method in c# and SQL server

Tags: c#

I have used decimal.round() method in c# which return as 
decimal.round (112.5) returns 112 but when I use round method in SQL server as 
select round (112.5,0) it return 113. What is the fault? Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 3):

```
Math.Round(112.5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server's `ROUND` method rounds .5 up always while (in default mode) `Math.Round` rounds to even (so 1.5 becomes 2, but 4.5 becomes 4). Round to even is commonly know as "Banker's Rounding".

Depending on which behaviour you want you can:

- Implement banker's rounding on SQL Server (see comment on the [`ROUND` page on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175003.aspx)).
- Use the option parameter on [`Math.Round`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx) to select a [different rounding method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the documentation for the decimal.round.

> The integer that is nearest to the d parameter. If d is halfway between two integers, one of which is even and the other odd, the even number is returned.
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4e2bye2(v=vs.110).aspx

The solution is to have a MidpointRounding parameter.

Please check this for simple samples: http://www.dotnetperls.com/math-round